# Understanding Scala -> syntax

Tags: scala, scala-collections, scala-2.10

I am getting a taste of Scala through the artima "[Programming in Scala](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/)" book.

While presenting the `Map` traits, the authors go to some lengths to describe the `->` syntax as a method that can be applied to any type to get a tuple.

And indeed:

```
scala> (2->"two")
res1: (Int, String) = (2,two)

scala> (2,"two")
res2: (Int, String) = (2,two)

scala> (2->"two") == (2, "two")
res3: Boolean = true
```

But those are not equivalent:

```
scala> Map(1->"one") + (2->"two")
res4: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,String] = Map(1 -> one, 2 -> two)

scala> Map(1->"one") + (2, "two")
<console>:8: error: type mismatch; 
found   : Int(2)
required: (Int, ?)
             Map(1->"one") + (2, "two")
```

Why is this so, since my first tests seem to show that both "pair" syntaxes build a tuple?

Regards.

Comment: In fact they are equivalent: (2->"two") is analog to ((2, "two")) and `Map(1 -> "one") + ((2, "two"))` works just fine. `Map(1 -> "one") + 2 -> "two"` wont work with the same error as `Map(1->"one") + (2, "two")`

Comment: Could you restate this as an answer so that I can accept it? :)

Comment: you could accept Rex answer although it will be good to mention why `map + 2 -> "two"` doesn't work (unfortunately, I don't know).

Comment: @om-nom-nom - Well, I do know that one.

Comment: @om-nom-nom `map + 2 -> "two"` will give you `(map + 2) -> "two"`: `+` and `->` have same precedence and are left-associative.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are exactly the same, thanks to this class in `Predef` (only partly reproduced here):

```
final class ArrowAssoc[A](val __leftOfArrow: A) extends AnyVal {
  @inline def -> [B](y: B): Tuple2[A, B] = Tuple2(__leftOfArrow, y)
}
@inline implicit def any2ArrowAssoc[A](x: A): ArrowAssoc[A] = new ArrowAssoc(x)
```

So now the question is when will `(a,b)` syntax be ambiguous where `(a -> b)` is not?  And the answer is in function calls, especially when they're overloaded:

```
def f[A](a: A) = a.toString
def f[A,B](a: A, b: B) = a.hashCode + b.hashCode
f(1,2)     // Int = 3
f(1 -> 2)  // String = (1,2)
f((1, 2))  // String = (1,2)
```

Map `+` in particular gets confused because it's overloaded with a multiple-argument version, so you could

```
Map(1 -> 2) + (3 -> 4, 4 -> 5, 5 -> 6)
```

and it thus interprets

```
Map(1 -> 2) + (3, 4)
```

as trying to add both `3` to the map, and then `4` to the map.  Which of course makes no sense, but it doesn't try the other interpretation.

With `->` there is no such ambiguity.

However, you can't

```
Map(1 -> 2) + 3 -> 4
```

because `+` and `-` have the same precedence.  Thus it is interpreted as

```
(Map(1 -> 2) + 3) -> 4
```

which again fails because you're trying to add `3` in place of a key-value pair.

Comment: Thanks for explaining why the parens are required, as suggested by @om-nom-nom.