# What do -> and ! mean in Scala

Tags: scala

I am reading some Scala code. What does the `->` mean in the following context?

```
var queries = { "Select apple from farm" -> None, "Select orange from fram" -> None, "Select blueberry from anotherFarm" -> Some( #randomStuff ) }
```

It looks like a list of lambda functions but I thought it should be `=>` in that case instead of `->`.

Also,
what does this single line code mean?

```
def onConnection(id) = { application ! turnOnApplication(id) }
```

Specifically, I am confused with the use of `!`. It doesn't seem to be a "NOT" as it is in most languages

Comment: You should seperate your questions and ask two different ones.

Comment: I can only post every 90 minutes. I changed the title. They are simple syntax questions so I think it's fine to be put together

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17644273/akka-in-scala-exclamation-mark-and-question-mark https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40248204/what-does-mean-in-scala/40248896#40248896 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17307472/understanding-scala-syntax

Comment: Where did you get the first one from? That does not look like valid syntax.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `->` symbol is one way to define a [tuple](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.4/scala/Tuple2.html) in Scala. The below  are all equivalent:

```
val apples1 = "Select apple from farm" -> None
val apples2 = ("Select apple from farm" -> None)
val apples3 = ("Select apple from farm", None)
```

As for the `!`:

```
def onConnection(id) = { application ! turnOnApplication(id) }
```

`!` in Scala can be the [negation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/operators.html) operator, but `!` in the above code snippet looks like [`tell`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/actors.html?language=scala#tell-fire-forget) from [Akka](https://akka.io/) (Akka is the main actor library for Scala). This pattern is used to send a message to an actor. So if `application` is a reference to an actor, the code snippet sends the result of `turnOnApplication(id)` to the `application` actor. From the linked documentation:

> "!" means “fire-and-forget”, e.g. send a message asynchronously and return immediately. Also known as tell.

Answer (score 1):

The thin arrow `->` is Tuple syntax. It's just a different way of writing Tuples. I.e.

```
val x: (Int, String) = 3 -> "abc"
```

Is the same as writing:

```
val x: (Int, String) = (3, "abc")
```

The arrow syntax is done by providing an implicit class `ArrowAssoc` which defines a method `def ->[B](y: B): (A, B)`. `ArrowAssoc` is part of `Predef` which is inserted into every Scala source file. You can find the docs [here.](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Predef$$ArrowAssoc.html)

The bracket syntax meanwhile is syntactic sugar done by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

You can form tuple using two syntaxes

1) Using comma

```
val tuple = (1, 2)
```

2) Using `->` (arrow)

```
val tuple = 1 -> 2
```

**Scala repl**

```
scala> val tuple = (1, 2)
tuple: (Int, Int) = (1,2)

scala> val tuple = 1 -> 2
tuple: (Int, Int) = (1,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Finding-symbols](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/finding-symbols) defines `->` as `Method provided by implicit conversion`. Just look at the methods tagged with `implicit` that receive, as parameter, an object of type that is receiving the method. For example:

```
"a" -> 1  // Look for an implicit from String, AnyRef, Any or type parameter
```

In the above case, `->` is defined in the class [ArrowAssoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Predef$$ArrowAssoc.html) through the method `any2ArrowAssoc` that takes an object of type `A`, where `A` is an unbounded type parameter to the same method.

[tutorialPoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/scala/scala_operators.htm) definde `!` as `It is called Logical NOT Operator. Use to reverses the logical state of its operand. If a condition is true then Logical NOT operator will make false.`