# Examples in Chisel that make use of MuxCase

Tags: chisel

How do I implement a 4:1 Mux in chisel without using 2:1 Muxes? Is there a way where we can select one of the inputs of the N inputs by having something like Mux(sel, A,B,C,D.......N) where N can be taken in as a parameter? I am aware of the MuxCase in chisel but I am yet to find an example that makes use of MuxCase, any sort of documentation or example regarding this is greatly appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of usages in rocket-chip in [MultiWidthFifo.scala](https://github.com/chipsalliance/rocket-chip/blob/master/src/main/scala/util/MultiWidthFifo.scala)

It's pretty straightforward. It takes a default value for what happens if none of the supplied conditions is true, otherwise it looks through a sequence of tuples, where each tuple  of the form (bool condition, result) often written condition -> result. The return value is the result from the first boolean condition that is true.

Here is a **toy** example of a module that passes the number of input bools into a module which then uses that value to construct a sequence of mux cases.

```
class UsesMuxCase(numCases: Int) extends Module {
  val io = IO(new Bundle {
    val output = Output(UInt(10.W))
    val inputs = Input(Vec(numCases, Bool()))
  })

  val cases = io.inputs.zipWithIndex.map { case (bool, index) =>
    bool -> index.U(10.W)
  }
  io.output := MuxCase(0.U(10.W), cases)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes I understand that, but my question is can we dynamically increase the number of cases to check at runtime rather than having a fixed number of cases? Can I add more cases using some sort of parameters?

Comment: I have edited the answer to show an example of how to use a parameterized number to control the number of cases passed to MuxCase

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Chick Markley has provided a [great example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58334765/10871073), but some codes are redundant. In fact, the example can simplified as:

```
class UsesMuxCase(numCases: Int) extends Module {
  val io = IO(new Bundle {
    val output = Output(UInt(10.W))
    val inputs = Input(Vec(numCases, Bool()))
  })

  io.output := MuxCase(0.U(10.W), io.inputs.zipWithIndex)
}
```

We don't need another `map { case (a, b) => a -> b }` after the `zip` operation, as both `(a, b)` and `a -> b` define tuples and are equivalent. This is a scala feature, refer to [What do -> and ! mean in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44501503/what-do-and-mean-in-scala)